# Trouble Getting Code to Perform Calculation in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working on homework and I am having an issue that I know you folks can help with. I am using jQuery and have coded my first button. I am trying to test it before I move on to the others as it will be simple to do once I understand this first one. I also have to code in for the user to input a basic color, but I have commented that out of my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Calculations</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#addition").click(function){
                var intVal1 = parseInt($("#inputValue1").val());
                var intVal2 = parseInt($("#inputValue2").val());
                //var colorString = $("#colorSelection").val();
                var total = intVal1 + intVal2;
                $("#result").html(total);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <p>Value 1: <input type="number" id="inputValue1"></p>
    <p>Value 2: <input type="number" id="inputValue2"></p>
    <!--<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Color: <input type="text" id="colorSelection"></p>-->
    <p>Choose an operation below:</p>
    <p>
        <button type="button" id="addition">+</button>
        <button type="button" id="subtraction">-</button>
        <button type="button" id="multiply">*</button>
        <button type="button" id="divide">/</button>
    </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: tell us your problem so we will be able to help

Comment: You have missed some brackets . Please check your browser console and fix them else your code is working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function(){
            $("#addition").click(function() { //this line
                alert("Hi");
                var intVal1 = parseInt($("#inputValue1").val());
                var intVal2 = parseInt($("#inputValue2").val());
                //var colorString = $("#colorSelection").val();
                var total = intVal1 + intVal2;
                $("#result").html(total);
            }) //this line
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I had looked over t several times and compared it to some of my other code on other stuff I did, but those little brackets skipped my eyes.